# update mysql table where rows are not in php array

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array of items:

```
$expiringDomains = array('dom1.com', 'dom2.com');
```

how can i run an update on my table to update all rows where the `domain` in the table is NOT in the array

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE FROM customer_domains set reminder1 = '', reminder2 = '', reminder3 = '' WHERE domain = '';");
```

i know i could do a PHP loop through the array but i want it to run as quick as possible - the array could get up to 20,000 items or more

Comment: `where domain NOT IN ('dom1', 'dom2')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quickest dirtiest way to execute unescaped, unprepared trusted data like this requires knowledge that your domains will be valid domains without `'` characters or other inject-able nonsense.

you also have an error in your SQL statement, there shouldn't be a FROM in an UPDATE statement.

```
<?php

$expiringDomains = array('dom1.com', 'dom2.com');

$query = "
  UPDATE customer_domains
  SET reminder1 = '', reminder2 = '', reminder3 = ''
  WHERE domain NOT IN ('".implode("','",$expiringDomains)."');
";

$sql = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using prepared statements you can do:

```
<?php
$expiringDomains = array('dom1.com', 'dom2.com');

// Build a string of comma separated question marks (as many as there are domains)
$qm = substr(str_repeat(',?', count($expiringDomains)), 1);

$sth = $db->prepare("
    UPDATE customer_domains SET reminder1 = '', reminder2 = '', reminder3 = ''
    WHERE domain NOT IN($qm)
");

$sth->execute($expiringDomains);
?>
```

**Edit**: If you are using MySQLi, you can do it in the following way, since MySQLi doesn't support arrays as `execute()` parameter *(thanks to Jeff in the comments)*.

```
call_user_func_array(array($sth, "bind_param"), $expiringDomains);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: But this is using PDO - it looks like OP is using MySQLi. Can't pass array as parameter to [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Actually, I wasn't aware of another MySQLi extension than the old `mysqli_query` etc... But anyhow OP can loop over the array to bind each of them using `bind_param()`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mysqli for that if you can avoid it, it'll just give you headaches. Use PDO instead. Something like:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare(
    "UPDATE mytable SET foo=1 WHERE domain NOT IN(" .
    implode(", ", array_fill(0, count($expiringDomains), "?")) .
    ")"
);

$sth->execute($expiringDomains);

$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

If you really want to use mysqli, the approach you'd use is similar but instead of providing the data in `execute()` you'd have to either make a very complicated single `bind_param` call (involving `call_user_func_array()` unless the number of elements in your array is fixed) or loop over making several `bind_param` calls.